# Java 11 HttpRequest with PATCH method

Tags: java, groovy, httprequest, java-11, java-http-client

I try to use the java 11 `HttpRequest` to call the msgraph webservice using the method PATCH:

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import groovy.json.JsonOutput;

access_token = "my_token";

def url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/group_id/drive/items/01P4AIIJ5QTIIAZ2FLEZBIZWRV6KEBIMM5/workbook/worksheets/%7B00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000%7D/range(address=\'A1\')'

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                                    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                                    .build();

jsonPayloadString = '{"values":["blabla"]}';


jsonPayload = HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonPayloadString.toString())

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                 .uri(URI.create(url))
                                 .PATCH(jsonPayload)
                                 .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                 .build();

HttpResponse response = httpClient.send(request,HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

The error :

> No signature of method:
>   jdk.internal.net.http.HttpRequestBuilderImpl.PATCH() is applicable for
>   argument types:
>   (jdk.internal.net.http.RequestPublishers$StringPublisher) values:
>   [jdk.internal.net.http.RequestPublishers$StringPublisher@280a600b]

the call itself works great, for instance in Postman. But I cannot make it work in groovy/java.

I used previously the `HttpUrlConnection` but it does not support PATCH. Is it actually possible using `HttpRequest`?

I could not find any working example of the use of the PATCH method on the Net.

Comment: `HttpRequest` uses `Builder` to build the request object, which has limited set of HTTP request types with build pattern, you can use `method` to support other request types. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.Builder.html)

Comment: For the line: 

`jsonPayload = HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonPayloadString.toString())`

isn't it `BodyPublisher` and not `BodyPublishers` as it says in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.html#ofString(java.lang.String)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to docs, you can use "[method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.Builder.html#method(java.lang.String,java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublisher))" to specify other kind of methods like PATCH, OPTIONS, TRACE, etc.

In your case:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                             .uri(URI.create(url))
                             .method("PATCH", jsonPayload)
                             .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                             .build();
```

Comment: gee, thanks a ton! what I wonder is, why are GET() and POST() treated as a dedicated method and the others not...

Comment: Probably because the developer who wrote the class thoughts that other methods are  more common to use. In my opinion PATCH was forgotten and it'll be added in other update.

Comment: 2024 and PATCH isn't there yet!